# Using Flash Media Gateway Application

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I got a IP Communications new account having following paramters:

```
        Originating IP   Destination IP       Protocol    Codec      Ports
```

(for example)65.154.35.210 ,  202.124.43.256  ,     SIP      ,    g729 / ,   2

Now i want to use it in default application of FMG i.e:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashmedia_gateway/flashmedia_gateway_sample_flashphone.swf

Its showing me connecting ...
Status is not getting update like: "Connection Failed" or "Connection Success".

Please tell me how to use the above information in this app, or please sugets me an app any other app to experience FMG.

Regards
Ankush

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a socket connection, refer to the documentation and different events which are dispatched by the [`Socket` class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html). Add event handlers to the following events and update the message box when the corresponding events fire.

> **close**: Dispatched when the server closes the socket connection.
>
> **connect**: Dispatched when a network connection has been established.
>
> **ioError**: Dispatched when an input/output error occurs that causes
> a send or load operation to fail.
>
> **securityError**: Dispatched if a call to Socket.connect() attempts to
> connect either to a server outside the
> caller's security sandbox or to a port
> lower than 1024.
>
> **socketData**: Dispatched when a socket has received data.

Comment: Hi ravi, thanks for replying but i think u hvnt understood the question i asked. I dont have the code , i am justing running the above mentioned application. So please tell me how to run that application using the above mentioned values from IP Communications